# FBX export from Blender 2.8 change scale

Tags: export

I am exporting a mesh in Fbx format with all the transformations applied and the     scene set in meters and when I import to max set system the scale of the mesh changes to cm.

I have tried to import to blender 2.79 and if I do any transformation to the mesh before exporting from Blender 2.8 it does not maintain the scale in meter even if I apply the transformations.
Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

> Blockquote
>   [image]